# Apache URL redirect using RewriteMap

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewritemap

I am struggling with the last part, writing proper RewriteRule (maybe I also need RewriteCond?).

I have this `mapping.txt`:

```
apple 30/products/apple.png
xerox 38/products/xerox-300.png
dell 3021/products/dell_img.png
...
```

with it I want to do URL redirects as following:

```
https://www.domain-a.com/product_img/apple -> https://www.domain-b.com/img/30/products/apple.png
https://www.domain-a.com/product_img/xerox -> https://www.domain-b.com/img/38/products/xerox-300.png
...
```

in my `.htaccess` I have:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteMap redirect_map txt:/home/username/domains/domain-a/public_html/product_img/mapping.txt
RewriteRule * ${redirect_map:$1} // <--- struggling with this line
</IfModule>
```

How do I write proper RewriteRule for my case? I've tried many options without any luck yet. Secondly, should I have these rules in `/public_html/.htaccess` or create a new one in `/public_html/product_img/.htaccess`?

Comment: Presumably you are getting a 500 Internal Server Error? (In which case check your error log.) You can't _create_ a `RewriteMap` in `.htaccess` - you need access to the server config. Do you have access to the server config?

Comment: @MrWhite, exactly that was my problem. Due to being a shared hosting, I am not able to use RewriteMap at all.

Comment: I've just noticed you have two different domains as well. You can't "rewrite" from one host to another - this will implicitly trigger an external redirect, which is not good for your server or users. You would need to implement a reverse proxy - but again, this is probably not possible on shared hosting.

Comment: Exactly, the redirects would be from my domain to some other 3rd party domain. Good to know. Best to solve in some other way without redirects.